# HDF5 installed via Conda, but the `hdf5` location couldn't be found

Tags: python, conda, hdf5, h5py, miniconda

I'm trying to install the recent version HDF5 1.12.1 (via `conda`) and h5py 3.6.0 (via `pip3`).

Both package were installed successfully through the recent version of Conda, but my environment does not contain HDF5.

**h5py**

```bash
# This was succesfully installed and found in the correct directory
pip3 show h5py

    Name: h5py\
    Version: 3.6.0 \
    Summary: Read and write HDF5 files from Python\
    Home-page: http://www.h5py.org \
    Author: Andrew Collette\
    Author-email: andrew.collette@gmail.com \
    License: BSD\
    Location: /home/goldpm1/miniconda3/envs/cnvpytor/lib/python3.7/site-packages\
    Requires: cached-property, numpy\
    Required-by: CNVpytor, selene-sdk, signatureanalyzer
```

**HDF5**

```bash
# conda list shows that hdf5 newest version is insatalled, but I can't find at all at the conda environment
conda list hdf5
     
Name             Version                   Build        Channel
hdf5              1.12.1      nompi_h4df4325_104    conda-forge

# I can't find actual hdf5 location in /home/goldpm1/miniconda3/envs/cnvpytor
which hdf5

    /usr/bin/which: no hdf5 in (............)
```

What happened in my Conda? How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the Conda version of `h5py` as managing the full stack of dependencies is exactly the problem that Conda was created to solve. That is, Conda will guarantee the correct dependencies are installed:

```bash
conda install h5py
```

Also, I'm not sure why an `hdf5` binary is expected. The `hdf5` package delivers a bunch of `bin/h5*` binaries, but no `hdf5`. Moreover, the Python package uses the `include/*.h` headers and then makes calls into the `lib/libhdf5.{so,dylib,dll}`, not a `hdf5` binary.

I should probably also mention that, at least for recent versions, `h5py` on PyPI bundles the HDF5 via wheels, i.e., uses static builds. In contrast, Conda packages mostly use dynamic linking, so packages can share single copies of dependencies. Furthermore, Conda uses hardlinking, so dependencies can even be single copies *across environments*.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @merv! Your solution worked for me after three hours of searching.

On RHEL 9.0, I installed R-Studio in Conda environment and I was trying to install `remotes::install_github("bnprks/BPCells", quiet = TRUE)` which was unsuccessful because of this error:

> Unable to locate libhdf5. Please install manually or edit compiler
> flags.